# Jquery-vsdoc not working using MVC4 Bundling ? and @Scripts.Render not working when included above </body> in _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Below is the vsdoc bundle I've added to BundleConfig, and have rendered the scripts in _Layout.cshtml. Yet I couldn't get the jquery intellisense working on the views. The only way i've got it working thus far is by pasting a reference to the view where I'm using Jquery. The other thing is that even an alert box doesn't work if I render the scripts above the `</body>` in _Layout.cshtml. However, it works if I render it in the `<head>` tag. Why is it ? Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks

```
**BundlesConfig**

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryIntellisense").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}-vsdoc.js"));
**Layout**
</footer>
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryIntellisense")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
     **View**
<h2>Jquery Test</h2>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { alert("hello"); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The VS doc is only used by Visual Studio. You do not need to include it in a bundle. Rendering it on a web page probably what is breaking your code, causing the `alert` at the bottom not to fire.

To get intellisense in a script file, add a reference to it in the script file:

```
/// <reference path="path/from/this/script/to/jquery-1.8.2.js" />
```

There is a shortcut to do this. Open the script file where you want to get jQuery intellisense. Then, in the solution explorer, find your `jquery-1.{whateverversion}.js` file. Click and drag that file from the solution explorer to your script file and it will automatically create a `/// <reference` with the correct path.

To get intellisense in your views, make sure your _references.js file has a reference to jQuery:

```
/// <reference path="path/from/_references.js/to/jquery-1.8.2.js" />
```

Comment: Thanks - How can I get the intellisense working for jquery then ? I'd like to use them both in views and in custom script files.

Comment: Include this in your javascript file:  /// <reference path="~/yourdirectory/jquery-vsdoc.js" /> (where yourdirectory is... your directory)

Comment: I don't think the intellisense is breaking the code. I have got rid of the '@Scripts.Render' for vs-doc, but still i couldn't get the alert box working unless i put the '@scripts.Render' for jquery in '<head>' tag. Seems it's a mvc4 issue. please have a look at the link below. http://raki-tech.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-is.html

Comment: It may not be the vs-doc scripts, but there is some script somewhere in the body (or late in the head) that is causing the error. I have a few MVC sites where jQuery is included at the end, just before the /body tag, and they work fine. Just remember the jQuery src has to be loaded onto the page sometime **before** any other scripts that use jQuery.